# Mulesoft cannot run a shell script

Tags: java, mulesoft

I am trying to run a shell script in a flow in Mulesoft's Anypoint Studio.

While I can get some basic shell to run I cannot get my script to run. This is what my script looks like:

```
#!/bin/ksh
export JWHome=${pwd}
export LOG4J_JAR=$JWHome/lib/log4j-1.2.7.jar
export CLASSPATH=$JWHome/lib/java.jar:$LOG4J_JAR:$JWHome
```

I set the above script as a payload and execute it from a Groovy script by running:

```
payload.execute().text
```

When I run this script I get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "#!/bin/ksh": error=2, No such file or directory
I get the same error when I remove "#!/bin/ksh" - For example when I run Export to set a variable.
```

How can I get this to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that what you did -you didn't provide enough details- is to use a Groovy script to execute the content of a string in the payload using the [execute() method](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#execute()). That is failing because a shell script is not a single command. Only a shell can interpret it, but not as command line.

You can try writing the shell script content to a file (example: myscript.sh, or use a temporary name), then execute the shell script by name (`"myscript.sh".execute()`). You will probably need to add the path to the file is correct otherwise the execute() method may not find it.

Comment: Hey Aled, you're correct in assuming that I execute the script from a Groovy script. I will try to place the script in a file and run it from there. I will update my question. In order to run the script file like you said I need to place it under `src/resources/main`, correct?

Comment: you need to put it in a place that the shell will find it. Note that the deployment directory is not the same as the source directory. And a shell will not know Java classpath to find it. The safest way is to use the full path.